# styling results from a text field in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am building a simple Rails blog, using a text field to write posts like this:

```
    <p>
        <%= f.label :content %>
        <%= f.text_field :content, :size=>"50" %>
    </p>
```

How can I style/format the output from this? When i submit a post and look at the developer tools in Chrome, the text is not added to a paragraph element so I don't know how to style it..

Comment: `How can I style/format the output from this? ` - what is this in this sentence? This form? This input? This page? What do you understand by output?

Comment: @BroiSatse- I believe he's wondering what to edit to change the page that is displayed after `:create` is done, which would be the `show` template typically (as I'm sure you know).

Answer (score 0):

After submitting the form, the rails default is to load the model's `show.html.erb` template.  Edit that template to change it structurally or apply CSS to the elements therein.